# Why doesn't BERT give me back my original sentence?

Tags: autoencoders, language-models

I've started playing with `BERT` encoder through the `huggingface` module.
[image]

I passed it a normal unmasked sentence and got the following results:
[image]

However, when I try to manually apply the softmax and decode the output:
[image]

I get back a bunch of unexpected `tensor(1012)` instead of my original sentence. BERT is an autoencoder, no?

Shouldn't it be giving me back the original sentence with fairly high probability since none of the input words was `[MASK]`? Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry, but I have trouble with zero-shot learning. I need at least a sample size of one to understand what is expected of me. Could you please point out what is specifically wrong with my question or edit it for me so that I can mimic the formatting later on? Thanks.

Comment: First, could you replace the screenshots in the post with actual text, please_